# Does the iPod Classic respond to the clicker buttons on the iPhone earbuds?

Tags: iphone, ipod, headphones, remote-control

I was pleasantly surprised to discover that the iPad supports the clickers on the iPhone headphones (volume up/down, play/pause, etc). Does the most recent iPod Classic series respond to these buttons as well?

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Check out [this link](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB770G/B?fnode=MTY1NDA3NA&mco=MTM3NDk2NzA) on Apple's site. I'm actually surprised to learn so many devices support it now.

- iPhone 4
- iPhone 3GS
- iPod touch (2nd generation)
- iPod classic (120GB 160GB - 2009)
- iPod nano (5th generation - video camera)
- iPod nano (4th generation - video)
- iPod shuffle (3rd generation)
- iPad